# Calendar_VisibleMonthChanged returns only only months changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, calendar

I have this code:

```
protected void Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender, MonthChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(Calendar1.VisibleDate.ToString("M, y"));
    Label2.Text = date.ToString("MM, yyyy") + "г.";
}
```

And when i change month in Calendar, Label2.text allways consists of months of 2015(current) year, even if i change month in Calendar 13 times. For example, in Calendar i see 1st January 2016, but in label still 1st January 2015.

Answer (score 0):

You ***may*** have found a bug.   In any event, this works:

```
Label2.Text = e.NewDate.ToString("MM, yyyy") + "г.";
```

Comment: But if i want to call a ShowYear method, when VisibleMonthChanged, how can i access NewDate from a method? 'code'
       `protected void Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender, MonthChangedEventArgs e)
        {
         ShowYear();
        }`  

        `protected void ShowYear()
        {
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(Calendar1.VisibleDate.ToString("M, y"));
            Label2.Text = date.ToString("MM, yyyy") + "г.";            
        }`

`Label2.Text = e.NewDate.ToString("MM, yyyy") + "г.";` doesn't work here

Comment: in this case `ShowYear();` would be `ShowYear(MonthChangedEventArgs e);` and `protected void ShowYear()` would be `protected void ShowYear(MonthChangedEventArgs e)`

Comment: @MohitShrivastava unfortunatelly when i call a method `ShowYear(MonthChangedEventArgs e);`  
 it returns error:
System.Web.UI.WebControls.MonthChangedEventArgs is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment on @Steve your code should be

```
protected void Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender, MonthChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    ShowYear(e); 
} 
protected void ShowYear(MonthChangedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Label2.Text = e.NewDate.ToString("MM, yyyy") + "г."; 
}
```

Comment: I can't find how can i do it

Comment: @DenisovJr. Just copy and paste and it should be working